# Cannot replicate simple codepen: CSS issue

Tags: css, codepen

I am trying to replicate this simple [codepen][1] (https://codepen.io/rdugert/pen/bGNBoZP)

When I copy HTML code and CSS (duly positioned in their respective tags) to my own file, I lose all the CSS and result shows as  plain HTML.

common coding structure:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something on the CSS init phase? I see the code setting is set to "SCSS"...

thanks.

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question and not a link to any third party site.

Comment: when it try to reproduce it to the same fiddle, here is the result: https://jsfiddle.net/rdugert/e7qgj192/1/

Answer (score 1):

That isn't css. It's *scss*.

You need to use scss conversor to trainslate it to css

Comment: what tool, should you recommend me to use? got an error with  online tools...

Comment: The error you have is because the online tools doesn't recognize some variables of codepen. I mean, in `@import "bourbon";`, what is bourbon?

Comment: @R_life_R Do not ask for tool recommendations. That is not allowed on SO. [What topics can I ask about?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: you can export as zip the codepen and see the all assets